# Flex mobile request to time.nist.gov

Tags: mobile, time, flex4, httpservice, urlrequest

How do I access the time provided by internet time services like time.nist.gov from within my Flex mobile application?

Is there a way to do this via URLRequest or HTTPService?

Alright, here is the call to the Yahoo WebServices with a simple HTTPService;

```
<s:HTTPService id="serverTime" url="http://developer.yahooapis.com/TimeService/V1/getTime?appid=myID" result="resultHandler(event)" resultFormat="e4x"/>
```

In my resultHandler, the trace on Timestamp already fails (returns no value);

```
private function resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void {
            // this works (outputs the xml as shown on Yahoo
            trace(event.result);

            var xmlResult:XML = event.result as XML;
            var timestamp:String = xmlResult.Timestamp;

            trace("stamp" + timestamp);
}
```

Comment: For whatever reason (I really have no clue), addressing child nodes via tag name doesn't work with the HTTPService, so I changed the return format to XML and addressed the child directly via XMLNode (XMLNode(xmlNode.childNodes[0]).firstChild.nodeValue).

Comment: I think you missed the root "Result" tag. So it's: var timestamp:String = xmlResult.Result.Timestamp

Comment: and, even better, why not use the resultFormat="object", then access the timestamp in your event handler like: event.result["Result"]["Tmestamp"]  (I prefer the [] versus the . notation)

Comment: With e4x you don't need to go up the tree till the root tag, but even with xml as the result format, accessing Result.Timestamp didn't work. Don't ask me why, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

time.nist.gov (or any other time server) use NTP protocol for communication, not HTTP, so you can't use URLRequest or HTTPService.
I don't know of any NTP client implementation in ActionScript. You may need to do your own.

Depending on your needs, you may use a webservice that provides "pretty accurate" time, like [Yahoo WebServices](http://developer.yahoo.com/util/timeservice/V1/getTime.html). This goes over HTTP, so you can use URLRequest or HTTPService in Flex.

Comment: Cheers mate, Yahoo is absolutely sufficient (I only need accuracy up to days so that's fine). I'll give it a try!

Comment: Alright, that works fine so far, except the parsing seems to cause an issue. I do get the whole Result XML like shown on the WebServices page. (My HTTPService's resultFormat is e4x), however, accessing the Timestamp node doesn't work as expected. I edited my initial post to illustrate the issue.